# GTK app and serial port handlers

Tags: serial-port, gtk3

I’m writing a GTK C application for Linux OS on an embedded board.

The first main window opens a serial (virtual) port for receive the data from a bar-code reader.
I’m using standard open() function (inside my OpenPort() function).
Then I call g_io_channel_new_file() and g_io_add_watch() to handle the rx signal.

Do I really need the standard open() call?

```
    if (g_config.fdRfid==-1)
        g_config.fdRfid = OpenPort( g_config.portRfid, B115200);

    if (g_config.fdRfid!=-1)
    {
        ShowMainMessage();
        
        GError *error = NULL;
        g_ioChannel = g_io_channel_new_file( g_config.portRfid, "r", &error);
        if (g_ioChannel)
        {
            guint source = g_io_add_watch( g_ioChannel, G_IO_IN | G_IO_PRI, serialRfidWatcher, &g_config);
            printf("> set watch ioCh: %p - source: %d\n", g_ioChannel, source);
        }
        else 
            gtk_label_set_text( GTK_LABEL(g_labelMsg2), error->message);
```

When I press a button I open a dialog child window: before that, I close the serial port by close() function and I disconnect the signal by g_io_channel_shutdown() function.
The returned status is 1 = G_IO_STATUS_NORMAL.

```
GIOStatus status = g_io_channel_shutdown( g_ioChannel, TRUE, NULL);
g_io_channel_unref(g_ioChannel);

if (g_config.fdRfid != -1) 
{
    ClosePort(&g_config.fdRfid);
}
```

Starting the dialog window I open again the same port (it is a window for test) and I reconnect the rx signal in the same previous way.
Now if I read a bar-code in my debug output (by printf) I see that both signal handler of the main window and the handler in the dialog are called.

Closing the dialog (closing the port and channel...) I return to main window. If I read a bar-code, three handler are fired, two on main window and one on the dialog.

How can i disconnect the signal handlers? I think my way is incomplete ..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**
I missed the call to

```
g_source_remove(source)
```

in the closing procedure.
Of course I changed the line to make `source` a global variable:

```
/*guint*/ source = g_io_add_watch( g_ioChannel, G_IO_IN | G_IO_PRI, serialRfidWatcher, &g_config);
```